# select multiple file using Dropbox.choose() function?

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

i am using dropbox.choose() function in my code but i am facing problem in multiple file selection its allow me only one file selection and also it not showing alert message after selection of file.

Let me know if any one have solution for it ?
Here is my code :

if i use `var option ={
  ...........};` then pop-up window open automatically when i refresh the page
so i use only `option={.........};`

Here is [DEMO LINK](http://collage.bluecoresys.com/dropbox/)

CODE:

```
options = {
    success: function(files) {
        alert("Here's the file link:" + files[0].link)
    },
    cancel: function() {
    },
    linkType: "direct",
    multiselect: true,
    extensions: ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx'],
};
Dropbox.choose(options);
```

Comment: Are you able, in the same browser, to select multiple files when you use the sample chooser available on https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js ?  This will narrow the issue down a bit.  It seems the same exact code as on that page though.

Comment: here is my hosted link http://collage.bluecoresys.com/dropbox/ just check it i used all things from  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks pretty reasonable, but it should probably be `var options = ...` (with the "var").

Make sure you're calling `Dropbox.choose` from a user action (like a click). Otherwise popup blockers might not allow the popup.

Perhaps you can try to make a simple web page that shows the problem and share the full HTML and JavaScript. I don't see obvious problems in the code snippet you show.

Comment: can you provide me any example how should i call Dropbox.choose on click ?

Comment: It looks like you're using the `<input>` tag, so this should all be taken care of for you. Just add `data-multiselect="true"` to the tag. I.e.: `<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file"  id="db-chooser" data-multiselect="true" />`